# Getting error C++ no matching function for call even having all constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, overloading

I tried to make a BigInt library supporting unit digit initialization and overloading * operator

I am having constructor "BigInt(int r[])" still "return BigInt(res)" is not working, where res in int array

Thank you for you time.

Compiler Error "error: no matching function for call to 'BigInt::BigInt(BigInt)'
         return BigInt(res);"

Here's is the code Iam compiling in Qt Creator

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BigInt{
public:
    int h[1000];

    BigInt(){
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) h[i] = -1;
    }
    BigInt(int n){
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) h[i] = -1;
        h[0] = n;

        //Assuming single digit
    }
    BigInt(int r[]){
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) h[i] = r[i];
    }
    BigInt(BigInt &b){
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) h[i] = b.h[i];
    }

    BigInt operator*(int n){
        int carry = 0;
        int res[1000] = {-1};

        int *a = &h[0];
        int *b = &res[0];

        while(1){

            int unitDigit = n*(*a) + carry;
            carry = unitDigit/10;
            unitDigit %= 10;

            *b = unitDigit;
            b++;
            a++;

            if(*a == -1){
                break;
            }

        }

        while(carry){
            int unitDigit = carry % 10;
            *b = unitDigit;
            carry /= 10;
            b++;
        }

        return BigInt(res);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, BigInt &b){
        int i;
        for(i = 999; b.h[i] == -1; i--)
            ;

        for(; i>=0; i--){
            out<<b.h[i];
        }

        return out;
    }
};

int main(){

    int input;
    cin>>input;

    BigInt result(1);

    for(int i=2; i<input; i++){
        result = result*i;
    }

    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this compiles fine for me - are yu sure you've posted the code with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constructor

```
  BigInt(BigInt &b){
     for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) h[i] = b.h[i];
  }
```

That does not seem right. If you wanted to provide a copy constructor, the argument needs to be `const&`.

```
  BigInt(BigInt const&b){
     for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) h[i] = b.h[i];
  }
```

After I changed that, I was able to build the program using your posted code.

Comment: @JohnBurger, not correct. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor.

Comment: Wow: when did they change _that_? That's broken a _lot_ of my code... I mean, not that it's difficult to change or anything, but... wow.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ... I will surely make habit of writing const

Answer (score 1):

Change the `BigInt(int r[])` constructor to `BigInt(const int *r)`.

Don't try to copy arrays; point to them instead.

Comment: Using `BigInt(int r[])` does not copy the array.

Comment: Yes, but it _looks_ like it, which is why I said "try".